# App crashing when TextView is changed inside onLocationChanged inside a fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, textview

I am a beginner at developing for Android. I in my app I got GPS and a navigation drawer working. My goal is to display coordinates in a fragment. I got the app to feed the GPS data into `logcat` and now I'm trying to change the text on `TextvView` from the `onLocationChanged` method. Changing text inside `onCreateView` works flawlessly.

It works like this:

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_gps, container, false);

    gpsLongitude = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.gps_longitude);
    gpsLongitude.setText("something");

    return myView;
}
```

But not when I do this:

```
private double longitude;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_gps, container, false);

    gpsLongitude = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.gps_longitude);

    return myView;
}

...

public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    Log.e("GPS", "found signal");
    longitude = location.getLongitude();
    gpsLongitude.setText("Longitude: " + Double.toString(longitude));

}
```

I get :

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference

(this happens right after i get : E/GPS: found signal in the logcat)

If I do this:

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    gpsLongitude = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.gps_longitude);
    gpsLongitude.setText("Longitude: " + Double.toString(longitude));
}
```

The same thing happens:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference

Doing this:

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    gpsLongitude = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.gps_longitude);
    gpsLongitude.setText("something");

}
```

Results in :

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/gps_longitude"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Longitude"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/gps_latitude"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Latitude"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/gps_altitude"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Altitude"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/gps_speed"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Speed"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:gravity="center">
        <Button
            android:onClick="onStartButtonClick"
            android:id="@+id/gps_start"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Start"
            android:textSize="20dp"/>
        <Button
            android:onClick="onStopButtonClick"
            android:id="@+id/gps_stop"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Stop"
            android:textSize="20dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Have been seeking for an answer for a few hours.

EDIT:

MainActivity.java :

```
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    GPSFragment locationListener = new GPSFragment();
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 23) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
            }, 10);
            return;
        }
    }
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0,locationListener);
```

Comment: Your scrollview xml, is this your mainactivity's layout?

Comment: No that is the fragment's xml file. But I found a solution myself look below I  posted the solution for people who might be stumbling upon the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
private double longitude;
private ViewGroup myView = null;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_gps, container, false);
    return myView;
}

public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    Log.e("GPS", "found signal");
    if (null != myView) {
        TextView gpsLongitude = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.gps_longitude);
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
        gpsLongitude.setText("Longitude: " + Double.toString(longitude));
    }


}
```

Comment: This does prevent the crash but does not display information into the Text View

Comment: TextView gpsLongitude = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.gps_longitude);
    longitude = location.getLongitude();
    gpsLongitude.setText("Longitude: " + Double.toString(longitude));

Answer (score 0):

Pass your view to the method like this

```
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location, View view) {

    gpsLongitude = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.gps_longitude);
    gpsLongitude.setText("something");

}
```

when you call your method pass the view

```
onLocationChanged(location,myView);
```

Comment: now it says : Class 'GPSFragment' must either be declared abstract or implemented abstract method 'onLocationChanged(Location)' in 'LocationListener'       Note: I have the code for GPS in my MainActivity.java. I have updated the question to include GPS code.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you implement the right interface of [`android.location.LocationListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html) in your `Fragment`

```
public class GPSFragment extends Fragment implements LocationListener {
...
}
```

You should request the `requestLocationUpdates` in `onCreateView()`

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_gps, container, false);
    gpsLongitude = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.gps_longitude);

    LocationManager lm= (LocationManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,0,0, (android.location.LocationListener) this);

    return myView;
}


@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    if(location==null){
        gpsLongitude.setText("Unknown location");
    }else {
        Log.e("GPS", "found signal");
        double longitude = location.getLongitude();
        gpsLongitude.setText("Longitude: " + Double.toString(longitude));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks will try this asap

Comment: Another quick question : will using this method of aquiring location cause the app to only track position when in this fragment, because I have multiple fragments and I want It do track position only when in this fragment. (my goal is to create an app that displays different sensor data)

Comment: I am not clear about your objective. But seem like you can archive your goal by create a BaseFragment as super class which will implement LocationListener and handle the location changed. Then let your multiple fragments you mentioned to extends from BaseFragment.

Comment: Thanks this solution works     Also: I'm not sure how to handle permissions for API 23

Comment: Ok so I'm using the navigation drawer preset. When The app launches It goes into a fragment called home after that there are different fragments intended for different sensors like GPS (wich is the only one I got working for now). This Is my first app so if I did a lot of mistakes that is why.

Comment: Nice! everyone made mistake.. dont worry :)

Answer (score -1):

Ok so I found a solution:

```
private double longitude;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_gps, container, false);

    gpsLongitude = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.gps_longitude);

    return myView;
}


public void showGPSData (View view) {
    gpsLongitude.setText("Longitude: " + Double.toString(longitude));
}


public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    longitude = location.getLongitude();
    showGPSData(myView);
}
```

So essentially I just created a method intended for changing text (showGPSData) in Text view, moved the Text view to onCreate and made so that the method (showGPSData) is called on location change.

Comment: I don't understand how this is any different from just directly inserting `gpsLongitude.setText("Longitude: " + Double.toString(longitude));` into onLocationChanged. It's essentially the same thing as your supposed "first failed try." And why even pass `myView` in `showGPSData(View view)` when you're not even using it???

Comment: Just directly inserting the setText doesn't work (that was my original question because when I do that the app just crashes when It calls onLocationChanged)